# [Angular/Ionic], call service in class (yes, again)

Tags: angular, class, ionic-framework, service

I need to call a service in an Angular class:

**MyService**

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
    constructor (private http: : HttpClient) { // HttpClient is just for the example
        console.log('MyService constructor');
    }

    getStuff(){
    }
}
```

**MyClass**

```
export class MyClass {
    constructor(){
        console.log('MyClass constructor');
    }

    doSomething(){
        // what i want to do
        return this.myService.getStuff();
    }
}
```

**In my main page**

```
let myArray: MyClass[];
myArray.push(new MyClass());
myArray.push(new MyClass());
myArray.push(new MyClass());
myArray[0].doSomething();
```

Adding @Injectable to MyClass is not an option as MyClass is a real instanciable class.

Manually create a MyService instance doesn't make sense as i want MyService do be a singleton and i dont want MyClass knows that MyService needs HttpClient (otherwise i would not use a service).

Using custom Injector in MyClass seems to be overkill and leads to the same issue as manually create a MyService instance.

I'm stuck, please help

Answer (score 1):

You can inject the Service class in your class as-

```
export class MyClass {
    constructor(private myService : MyService){ //It will inject new instance of MyService
        console.log('MyClass constructor');
    }

    doSomething(){
        // what i want to do
        return this.myService.getStuff();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well... no, this only  works on `@Component` or `@Injectable` classes (which are instanciated by Angular). Not on standalone classes (which are instanciated manually).

Comment: You can decorate your class with `@Injectable`. Do you see any issue with that ?

Comment: Yes, the issue is i want to instanciate MyClass with `new MyClass()`. use `@Injectable` decorator would only move the problem to the calling class.
Furthermore, if i use `@Injectable` (and add MyClass as provider to NgModule), this would change MyClass to be a service, i.e a singleton

Comment: You are seeking for `Dependency Injection` feature but without following the `Dependency Injection Process`.
1. `@Injectable` will just not move the problem of calling class but it will `@Inject` all other dependencies.
2. As long as `Singleton` is concerned, you can control at what level you want your class to be instantiated at component level.
If you still think its not fitting in your requirement then you must be looking for something else.

Comment: That is what i'm saying. MyClass is a standad class.I dont want it to be injected.
I just want to be able to call a service inside this class

Answer (score 0):

Dependency injection is one of the main asset of the Angular Framework. As Sunil said you can inject your service directly via MyClass constructor. It will automatically be instantiated and ready to use. You can also check the official documentation [here](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection).